# How to show overlapping between activites while transition

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-animation

The following code is performing animation from left to right. The problem is that while transition it displays black background, and in transition time i want to display the background activity.

Kindly guide me how to display background activity while transition.

```
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <alpha android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
    <alpha android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

Comment: Android has built in transitions for this, overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right); -- those don't work for you?

Comment: yup i am unable to get these. I had to create these `xml` files